# How to find the $\sigma(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The question is let $X$ be a random variable, and $A,B \in F$ and $A \cap B = \phi$ , and $X= -3\mathbb{I_A} +7  \mathbb{I_B}$ , where $\mathbb{I}$ is a characteristic function.What is $\sigma(X)$?

Comment: What does the notation $\sigma(X)$ mean? Is that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the variable $X$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @GáborPálovics If the notation means what I think it means, no it is not.  The question neglects the fact that $X(\omega)=0$ when $\omega\notin A\cup B$.

Comment: More to the point, a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under union.  Is $A\cup B \in \sigma(X)$ for your proposed $\sigma(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a random variable $Y$ that takes a finite number of values, say $y_1,\ldots, y_k$ (all $y's$ are distinct), then  the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$ is the collection of all sets of the form $Y^{-1}(A)$, where $A\subset\{y_1,\ldots,y_k\}$. There are $2^k$ elements in $\sigma(Y)$.

In your case, since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $X$ takes three values $\{-3,7,0\}$ if $A\cup B\neq\Omega$, or two values $\{-3,7\}$ if $A\cup B=\Omega$. In the former case, $\sigma(X)$ has $2^3=8$ elements:
$$\begin{align}
\sigma(X)&=\{X^{-1}(\emptyset), X^{-1}(\{-3\}), X^{-1}(\{7\}),X^{-1}(\{0\}), X^{-1}(\{-3,7\}),X^{-1}(\{-3,0\}), X^{-1}(\{0,7\},X^{-1}\{-3,0,7\}\}=\\
&=\{\emptyset,A,B,(A\cup B)^c, A\cup B, A\cup (A\cup B)^c, B\cup(A\cup B)^c,\Omega\}
\end{align}
$$